# I can be many things, and with a few changes become many more. What am I?

Tags: riddle, word

On my own I can be a lump of fat, or many other things.

If I lose Kay and add other things (not necessarily in the order given below), I change entirely:

- Add you, the ocean, and a Canadian stereotype, and I'll burn your skin.
- Add a tiny robot without a wall and the city of angels, and I become quite stretchy.
- Add something of mine and I become spiritual or supernatural
- Add a hemisphere and I'm something usually found in or around the house

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are:

> Stick

Add you, the ocean, and a Canadian stereotype, and I'll burn your skin.

> You: u
>  ocean: sea: c
>  Canadian: eh: a
>  **CAU**stic

Add a tiny robot without a wall and the city of angels, and I become quite stretchy.

> Robot: Wall-E: e
>  City of Angels: LA
>  **ELA**stic

Add something of mine and I become spiritual or supernatural

> Mine: My
>  **MY**stic

Add a hemisphere and I'm something usually found in or around the house

> Hemisphere: Dome (thanks, [@Forklift](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/36638/forklift))
>  **DOME**stic

Comment: I think you are missing domestic :)

Comment: Ahyes. Dome. Good one. :)

Comment: Eleven minutes... nicely done. I didn't expect this one to be too hard... for a bonus, what's the lump of fat?

Comment: A stick of butter (though that terminology is I think US-specific)